# Getting error while loading swagger-ui.html in spring(5.0.0.RELEASE) mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger-2.0

**Could not resolve reference because of: Could not resolve pointer: /definitions/Error does not exist in document**

I followed this link http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api , but getting above error while I add  globalResponseMessage() methhod for custom response message.I can't understand what's the reason.
Please help....TIA

```
 @Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .consumes(getContentType())
            .produces(getContentType())
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
            .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET, newArrayList(
                    new ResponseMessageBuilder()
                            .code(500).message("500 message")
                            .responseModel(new ModelRef("Error")).build(),
                    new ResponseMessageBuilder()
                            .code(403)
                            .message("Forbidden!!!!!")
                            .build()));
}
```

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue and found that one as a suggestion - https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1443 before test it I discuss with my team and we didn't need to override the default response, so I just removed it and didn't test the suggestion from hydra and jonaskoperdraat

Answer (score 9):

You have two alternatives:

1) Replace "Error" with "string" (lower case).

```
new ResponseMessageBuilder()
                        .code(500).message("500 message")
                        .responseModel(new ModelRef("string")).build(),
```

2) Replace "Error" with the name of the class you use for error information in the response body (or define an `Error` class for that). Example:

```
new ResponseMessageBuilder()
                        .code(500).message("500 message")
                        .responseModel(new ModelRef("ErrorInfo")).build(),
```

In this example, class `ErrorInfo` should be in the classpath of your web application (could be in a lib shared by several web apps). Example:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ErrorInfo {

    private String url;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "HTTP Status Code")
    private int statusCode;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "HTTP Reason Phrase")
    private String reasonPhrase;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Mensage to the user")
    private String message;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Ticket created on IT help desk if applicable", required = false)
    private String helpDeskTicket;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Debug information (e.g., stack trace), not visible if runtime environment is 'production'", required = false)
    private String debugInfo;

    public ErrorInfo() {
        // required by Jackson deserialization.
    }

    // ... other constructors, get/set methods...

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use primitives classes, like String. In case to use custom classes (like Error), you should resolve this model adding `additionalModels(typeResolver.resolve (CustomResponseClass.class))` in the Docket definition. Here is a code that works fine:

```
@Autowired
TypeResolver typeResolver;

@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
          .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
          .directModelSubstitute(Object.class, java.lang.Void.class)
          .select()
          .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withMethodAnnotation(ApiOperation.class))
          .build()
          .pathMapping("/")
          .apiInfo(apiInfo())
          .additionalModels(typeResolver.resolve (MensagemVo.class) )
          .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET,
                newArrayList(new ResponseMessageBuilder()
                            .code(500)
                            .message("Execution error message")
                            .responseModel(new ModelRef("String"))
                            .build(),
                      new ResponseMessageBuilder()
                            .code(422)
                            .message("Validation error message")
                            .responseModel(new ModelRef("MensagemVo"))
                            .build())
          );
}
```

Where `TypeResolve` is from `com.fasterxml.classmate` package.

Image of result:
[documentation result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7vrA.png)