# Swagger 2.0 Could not resolve reference because of: Could not resolve pointer

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to integrate swagger 2.0 with Spring Boot. Whenever I am going to hit to any Controller class API such as (POST,GET,DELETE,PUT). I am getting 
"**Could not resolve reference because of: Could not resolve pointer: /definitions/Error does not exist in document**
" excption .

This is my Swagger configuration code.

**SwaggerConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.x.x.controller"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build().useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
            .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET, errorList())
            .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.POST, errorList())
            .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.PUT, errorList())
            .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.DELETE, errorList());
}

private List<ResponseMessage> errorList() {

    List<ResponseMessage> errorList = new ArrayList<ResponseMessage>();

    errorList.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(400).message("Some error message")
            .responseModel(new ModelRef("Error")).build());

    errorList.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(401).message("Some error message")
            .responseModel(new ModelRef("Error")).build());

    errorList.add(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(404).message("Some error message")
            .responseModel(new ModelRef("Error")).build());

    return errorList;
}
```

}

[image: Error Image]

**Thank you.**

[image: Swagger Block]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error while loading swagger-ui.html in spring(5.0.0.RELEASE) mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588046/getting-error-while-loading-swagger-ui-html-in-spring5-0-0-release-mvc)

Comment: Hey Thanks @Arnaud for reply. It is working fine. but there 2 sections or blocks are displaying which look ugly, such as one for "string" another for "message" . Is there a way to make them in single block. I just added the image , please take a look once.