# Swagger Error: Could not resolve reference

Tags: .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have asp.net core 3.1 web API project which has a controller method accepting the JObject as a body param. When launching SwaggerUI, there are no errors. When I am expanding the available POST request, errors are shown up as you can see in below snippet:

**Controller**

```
public class LocationsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    Route("validlocations")]
    async Task<IActionResult> ValidateLocationsAsync(JObject jsonData)
    {
    //
    }
}
```

**Error Snippet**
[image]

Could you please help me with this error.

Comment: Please refer to  :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588046/getting-error-while-loading-swagger-ui-html-in-spring5-0-0-release-mvc

Answer (score 0):

When i tried with below code it's working for me.

```
 public class LocationsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("validlocations")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ValidateLocationsAsync(JObject jsonData)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Can you share your stratup.cs where you configured services for Swagger ?

Comment: The error shows on the header of the swagger page, could you please check it once